# Android - set default menu inflater color to white?

Tags: java, android

I would like to set the default menu inflator background color to white for any and all menu items created in OnCreateMenuOptions activity please?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to create a Theme based on another one (Or create one from scratch). Something like this will define your theme in the resources:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>    
    <style name="Base" parent="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar">
       <item name="android:background">@android:color/white</item>             
    </style>
</resources>
```

Then you need to apply it to the application in your manifest:

```
<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name"  android:theme="@style/Base">
```

Comment: Hello, I need the buttons when i press menu key on device to have white back ground. each item in my menu inflator has black color i need white as my icon images are white and i want to blend in button.

Comment: See my previous answer. What did you find? Did you have any problem?